# I use function in my code and somehow it doesnt work anymore

Tags: c, function

So I was practicing some coding about how functions work and I ran into a problem:
The code is meant to reverse a number. The algorithm works perfectly well so I don't have any problem with that. But I want to use functions in my code so I edited it like below and somehow it doesn't work anymore(there was no error, but when I run the code, after I entered in the first scanf, the code stopped and stays like that, no response). Can someone help me with this pls (This question may sound a little stupid but I'm just trying to be better at it :v)
Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int input(int *a) {
    scanf("%d", &*a);
}

int revint(int *a, int *b){
    int c;
    while(a != 0)
    {
        c = *a % 10;
        *b *= 10;
        b += c;
        *a /= 10;
    }
    return *b;
}

int output(int b) {
    printf("%d", b);
}

int main(){
    int a;
    int b = 0;
    input(&a);
    revint(&a, &b);
    output(b);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** What happened when you tried it?  Did you get an error message? If you did get an error, paste the entire message instead of paraphrasing. Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?

Comment: `while(a != 0)` will be an endless loop in your case. It should be `while(*a != 0)`

Comment: What is the point of `&*a`?

Comment: I'm thinking `b += c;` needs to be addressed, too.

Comment: @AndyLester i edited my question, thank you!! <3

Comment: Why do you even need those pointers?

Comment: @bereal i dont know, i put those in and my code doesn't show any warnings and errors anymore.

Comment: What do you mean by reverse a number? If the number is `123` you want `321`?

Comment: @oda technically yes

Comment: "i dont know, i put those in and my code doesn't show any warnings and errors anymore." You should never put in code that you don't know what it's doing or why. This is especially true of code that stops warnings and errors from appearing. Warnings are there to tell you that something is wrong. You should solve the problem that they are warning you of, rather than just trying to shut them up. It's like the "Check Oil" light on a car's dashboard. If it comes on, you should stop and solve the problem, instead of just covering up the light so you don't have to look at it anymore.

Comment: What do you mean by "reverse a number"?  It seems that you mean "reverse the string representation of a number", which demonstrates that your approach is incorrect.  You are using `scanf` to convert a string to an integer, and then manipulating that integer, and then using `printf` to convert the integer back to a string.  You should instead just do all your work on a string.

Comment: Your code has no comments and poor variable names. This makes it very hard to follow, especially when you return to your code months later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

1. `input()` and `output()` do not have a `return` statement and should be declared to return `void` in your code.
2. It makes more sense for `input()` to return the value rather then fill a pointer parameter. Therefore in my version `input()` does return a proper `int` value.
3. Several occurrences of `a`, `b` in `revint()` should be `*a`,`*b` (since `a` and `b` are pointers and we need to de-reference it first).

See the code below:

```
int input(void) {
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    return a;
}

int revint(int *a, int *b)
{
    int c;
    *b = 0;
    while (*a != 0)
    {
        c = *a % 10;
        *b = *b * 10 + c;
        *a /= 10;
    }
    return *b;
}

void output(int b) {
    printf("%d", b);
}

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    int b = 0;
    a = input();
    revint(&a, &b); // passing the addresses
    output(b);
    return 0;
}
```

NOTE: For simplicity the `input()` function doesn't validate that `scanf()` actually succeeded. In should better be done in the real code in which the user is handling.

Better `scanf()`:

```c
if (scanf("%d", &a) != 1) 
{
    fprintf(stderr, "bad input\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

In the real code the user can consider retrying getting the input as long as it is invalid.

**Update:**
As you can see in @Gerhard's answer, `revint` could be re-written to avoid the pointer semantics altogether. It will indeed make the code simpler and for this particular use case I actually think it is better.
My answer was written trying to maintain as much as possible the semantics that the user introduced in his question code. So I suggest you apply my solution only if it really makes sense for you to pass pointers.

Comment: `input` could return the return value of `scanf`, also `scanf("%d", &*a)` is redundant, could be reduced to `scanf("%d", a)`.

Comment: What you need is, `if (scanf("%d", &a) != 1) exit(1);`

Comment: @alex01011, @Darth-CodeX I updated my answer based on your first 2 comments. About `scanf` - you are right, but I wanted to do the minimal changes required to the user's code. I will add a comment about it though.

Comment: The thing is, if you type anything but a number, with its current format, `input` will just return that undefined value. IMO it's better to check the return value, exit, or retry for a valid input. Retrying makes more sense, otherwise there isn't really a reason for a dedicated `input` function.

Comment: @Darth-CodeX  It is not guaranteed that `scanf` will set `errno` so `perror("...")` may not work as expected [per standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.19.6.4)

Comment: @Darth-CodeX thanks. Accepted the edits.

Answer (score 1):

`input` changed to use the pointer correctly (`&*a`).

Removed the pointers to `revint` as it is not helping and your code had an point error there (`b += c;` modifies pointer not value).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void input(int *a) {
    scanf("%d", a);
}

int revint(int a){
    int b = 0;    
    int c;
    while(a != 0)
    {
        c = a % 10;
        b *= 10;
        b += c;
        a /= 10;
    }
    return b;
}

int output(int b) {
    printf("%d", b);
}

int main(){
    int a;
    int b = 0;
    input(&a);
    b = revint(a);
    output(b);
    
    return 0;
}
```